# Silverstripe Gridfield Export CSV misses first column

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am setting custom export columns in a ModelAdmin for the 'Export to CSV' - the resulting csv file always has blank first column values, no matter what I set for the column - the column name is there, just no values...

in ModelAdmin:

```
public function getExportFields()
{
    $model = singleton($this->modelClass);
    if ($model->hasMethod('getExportFields')) {
        return $model->getExportFields();
    }
    return singleton($this->modelClass)->summaryFields();
}
```

In Model:

```
public function getExportFields() {
    return [           
        'OutageDate', 
        'Reference',
        'Notice',
        'Active'
    ];
}
```

The result is always like:

[image]

I can put in a blank column to get the actual data I need:

```
public function getExportFields() {
    return [ 
        '',          
        'OutageDate', 
        'Reference', ...
```

[image]

Any idea why this is happening / fix?